# How to get available height of widget <n> levels above current widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to size a scrollable `ListView()` according to the available height of the **Widget()** 2 levels up. The code below is wrapped in two other `Container()`s.

Therefore I use **MediaQuery()**. Unfortunately, I use it using context, which is passed in at top. Thus, I suppose I get the space of the whole window.

**Q: How to retrieve the size of the widget  levels above the current Widget?**

```
Container(
          width: UIDefaults.columnWidth,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(children: [
            topItems,
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 180,    // <*****
                child: Scrollbar(
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                    controller: _controllerOne,
                    child: ListView(
                      controller: _controllerOne,
                      children: childs,
                      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    )))
          ]))
```

**Additional question:** Which does Scrollbar(ListView()) not use the exact remaining height?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to give your listView the same height as your Container (two levels up)? if that is the case use an Expand() widget to make your ListView use the same height as your container.